# Design an algorithm for the single source shortest path problem that runs in time O(k(|V|+|E|))

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, directed-graph

Suppose we are given a directed graph `G = (V, E)` with potentially positive and negative edge lengths, but no negative cycles. Let `s ∈ V` be a given source
vertex. How to design an algorithm for the single-source shortest path problem that runs in time `O(k(|V | + |E|))` if the shortest paths from s to any other vertex takes at most `k edges`?

Answer (score 1):

Here`s O(k(|V | + |E|)) approach:

1. We can use Bellman-Ford algorithm with some modifications
2. Create array D[] to store shortest path from node s to some node u
3. initially D[s]=0, and all other D[i]=+oo (infinity)
4. Now after we iterate throught all edges k times and relax them, D[u] holds shortest path value from node s to u after <=k edges
5. Because any s-u shortest path is atmost k edges, we can end algorithm after k iterations over edges

   Pseudocode:

   > for each vertex v in vertices:
   >      D[v] := +oo
   >
   > D[s] = 0
   >
   > repeat k times:
   >   for each edge (u, v) with weight w in edges:
   >          if D[u] + w < D[v]:
   >             D[v] = D[u] + w